# How to remove if data is not in the array in Mongodb

Tags: python, mongodb

I'm new to MongoDB and Python so recently I was doing a project and I come across this problem. Here's my MongoDB data view of it.

[image]

So the problem I'm having is in the `contacts:Object` there's `phone,email and address` but some just got `email and address only`.What I would like to do for it is,I want to remove those data array that is missing `phone`.What is the right operations for MongoDB and for Python?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use `$exist` in `deleteMany`, jsut try

```
deleteMany({ "contacts.phone": { $exists: false}})
```

Comment: if its inside in an array,is it the same way of doing it ? for example like : "data":[{"date":{"$date":"2021-01-19T00:00:00.000Z"},"price":0.16239,"volume":1661},{"price":0.14383,"volume":2486},{"date":{"$date":"2021-01-20T00:00:00.000Z"},"price":0.11743,"volume":2517},{"date":{"$date":"2021-01-23T00:00:00.000Z"},"price":0.37009,"volume":262381}] .. there's missing date on some data ... what's the command for tht?@Mohammad Yaser Ahmadi

Comment: no, for delete a field from array you should use another way

Comment: How is it can you show me? thanks in advance

Comment: can you show me a complete document in db, because every document is a object, send me a complete object

Comment: {"_id":{"$oid":"6006e7f81cc42f9c116e8dc2"},"country":"my","keyword":"face mask","platform":"shopee","startDate":{"$date":"2021-01-01T00:00:00.000Z"},"data":[{"date":{"$date":"2021-01-19T00:00:00.000Z"},"price":0.16239,"volume":1661},{"price":0.14383,"volume":2486},{"date":{"$date":"2021-01-20T00:00:00.000Z"},"price":0.11743,"volume":2517},{"date":{"$date":"2021-01-23T00:00:00.000Z"},"price":0.37009,"volume":262381}]}.. this is the complete db.. as you see there missing date in few data .. so how am i going to just remove the object without date?

Comment: for this data, answer is completely different, can you write a new question

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried:

```
 try: <to get that data>
 except: <will happen if "try" to get data fails -> then <delete the data or array that you want>
```